# Selective silent mode

Tags: android

I had  developed an app which  will selectively rings for certain numbers even if the phone is in silent mode.I had written the code for making it louder in a broadcast receiver.

The broadcast receiver is

```
     AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

     switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
         case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
             Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
             profileStatus = 1;
             break;
         case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
             Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
             break;
         case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
             Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
             profileStatus= 2;
             break;
     }
    System.out.println("The Profile Status"+profileStatus);
    System.out.println("The Old Profile Status"+oldProfileStatus);
    System.out.println("The Count = "+count  );

  if(profileStatus==1)
  {
        System.out.println("ProfileStatus"+profileStatus);

     OpenHelper db = new OpenHelper(context);
     //Getting Data From The DataBase

     CONTACT_DATA = db.Contact_Records();

     if (CONTACT_DATA.size() > 0)
     {
       //Log.e("ARRAY", "not null"); 

       for(int i =0;i<CONTACT_DATA.size();i++)
       {
           HashMap<String, String> map = CONTACT_DATA.get(i); 
           phone_number     =  map.get("phone_number"); 
       }
     }


         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         final AudioManager mobilemode = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         if(null == bundle)
                 return;

         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

         String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);
         if(state.equals("IDLE"))
         {

             System.out.println("THE STATE IS IDLE");
             mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

         }



         if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
         {
                 String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);        
                 Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number:from receiver------------------ " + phonenumber);
                 String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;



                 AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                 bundle = intent.getExtras();
                 this.context = context;

                 if(null == bundle)
                         return;


                 state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                 if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                 {
                         check();
                         PhoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                           for(int i =0;i<CONTACT_DATA.size();i++)
                           {
                               HashMap<String, String> map = CONTACT_DATA.get(i); 
                               phone_number     =  map.get("phone_number"); 
                                 if (PhoneNumber.equals(phone_number)) {
                                }
                            if((PhoneNumber.equals(phone_number)))
                            {
                                makeitNormal();
                                maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                oldProfileStatus = profileStatus;
                                System.out.println("The Profile Status==="+oldProfileStatus);
                                count=1;
                            }
                           }

                 }
                 if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                 {
                     makeItSilent();
                     mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                 }

                 if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
                 {
                     makeItSilent();
                     mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

                 }
```

//

```
 }
         }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("The System  Is In Normal Mode ");
      count=0;
  }
 }
 private void check() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      ringerMode=maudio.getRingerMode();

    }

    private void makeitNormal() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    }


    private void makeItSilent() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      int ringer=maudio.getRingerMode();
      if (ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT){

          maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

      }else if(ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
          maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
      }
      else if(ringerMode==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
          maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
      }

    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

The problem i am facing is
1)It is not ringing on the first time after the installation.After that it works perfectly
2)It is not working in HTC phone but it is working in samsung

Answer (score 1):

Your BroadcastReceiver is doing too much. It only lives as long as its onReceive() method, so you're not getting all the functionality you are putting into it. Try moving your volume manipulation code into a Service, and use the BroadcastReceiver as a simple proxy to tell the Service when a call is incoming. You should generally avoid heavy operations from within the context of a BroadcastReceiver.

Also, just calling setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) is not always sufficient to un-silence the ringer. You will also need to call setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false) and setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, someAudibleVolume, 0). On many devices, the ringer mode can be "normal" while the ringer volume is "0".

BTW I have written an app very similar what you describe, and will wish you luck :). You will see some of the worst fragmentation in the Android device ecosystem when trying to manipulate the ringer volume consistently. e.g. on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, you can easily override and manipulate the volume after an incoming call starts. Yet on a Galaxy S3 the ringer volume ignores attempts to change it while a call is incoming, and requires some clever (read "hackish") workarounds.

Comment: Hi ErikR, will you be able to share your clever workarounds for S3 and other Samsung devices?

Comment: I have posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477865/setringermode-to-normall-during-incoming-call-doesnt-work-on-samsung-devices will you be able to answer it? Thank you.